# How to use if with array elements in c++

Tags: c++

I want to receive only positive numbers from the user which are less than or equal to `4` 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   unsigned int n;
   cin>>n;
   unsigned int arr[n];
   for (int i =0 ;i<n ; i++){
   if (arr[i]<=4)
   cin>>arr[i];
   }

}
```

What am I doing wrong with my code? It receives numbers which are greater than `4` .

Comment: Down voter, please explain.

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: `unsigned int arr[n];` (where `n` is not a compile time constant) is not C++.  (It is supported by some compilers).  Your problem is that `array[i]` is uninitialized when you test it.  I think you want: `do (cin>>arr[i];) while (arr[i] > 4;`

Comment: How can the user add the first number ? You are checking condition even before the user inputs

Comment: How did it compiled? As i remember, such kind of an array expects a constant for it's size.

Comment: @GoverNator: Some compilers allow it as an extension, and have it switched on by default. Causing merry hell when you try to port to a different platform.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok then, thanks.

Comment: @N.Ivanov my questions is obviously clear.

Comment: Well based on the number of downvotes that you have it is obviously not.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy You would have found what's wrong easily with the debugger. Stack Overflow isn't meant as a compensation of doing that yourself 1st before asking.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of your code is undefined. You are *reading* elements of the array before writing to them.

And then you don't check the value inputted by the user.

Note also that *variable length arrays* are not standard C++ (`unsigned int arr[n];` declares such an array). Use a `std::vector` instead?

Really the best way to sort out these problems is to use a good line-by-line debugger.

Comment: Should I use do while?

Comment: I'd consider writing a separate function to read in each individual value.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int input = 0u; // Holds user input
    unsigned int nextPos = 0u; // Next free position in our array
    unsigned int arraySize = 0u; // The size of the dynamic array
    unsigned int* array = nullptr; // Pointer to our dynamic array

    // Ask the user for the array size
    cout << "Please Enter The Array Length" << endl;
    cin >> arraySize;

    // using array = int[arraySize] wouldn't work because the compiler won't know what value the number is at compile time.
    // instead we use the 'new' keyword to allocate some memory while the program is running
    // this is called dynamic allocation
    array = new unsigned int[arraySize];

    // The reason it's a while loop instead of a for loop is to only insert numbers into the array
    // when the pass the rule if input <= 4u (the u part just means it's unsigned)
    while(nextPos < arraySize) {
        // Here we ask for an input and store it in the same named input variable
        cout << "Please Enter A Valid Number" << endl;
        cin >> input;

        // Does the input pass the check?
        if (input <= 4u) {
            // If so store it in the current position in the array and increment
            // the line below is the same as doing
            // array[nextPos] = input;
            // nextPos = nextPos + 1u;
            array[nextPos++] = input;
        } else {
            // When the input doesn't meet the rule, complain about an invalid number
            cout << input << " is an invalid number" << endl;
        }
    }

    // A rule in C++ is that we need to manually release any memory we allocate using new
    // it would be 'delete variable' for objects or 'delete[] variable' for arrays
    delete[] array;
}
```

Comment: Down voting for the use of raw new when `std::vector<unsigned> array(arraySize);` works so much better

Comment: This would be better as `for (unsigned nextPos = 0; nextPos < arraySize;)`.  Even better would be:  `std::vector<unsigned> array; array.reserve(arraySize); while (array.size() < arraySize) ... array.push_back(input); ... `

Comment: Don't forget to reset the stream if something that can't be parsed into an `int` is encountered. Also, consider `std::vector` with a `push_back` idiom.